# How to use enum for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I try to get `status` of order with the help `enum`.

**OrderStatusEnum**

```
class OrderStatusEnum extends DictionaryEnum
{
    const CREATED = 1;
    const PAID = 2;
    const we = 3;
    const re = 4;
    const tr = 5;
    const ty = 6;
    const yu = 7;
    const ui = 8;
    const io = 9;
    const uy = 10;

    const STATUS = [
        self::CREATED => 'enum.week.monday',
        self::PAID => 'enum.week.tuesday',
        self::we => 'enum.week.monday',
        self::re => 'enum.week.tuesday',
        self::tr => 'enum.week.monday',
        self::ty => 'enum.week.tuesday',
        self::yu => 'enum.week.monday',
        self::io => 'enum.week.tuesday',
        self::uy => 'enum.week.monday',
    ];

    protected static array $enumItems = self::STATUS;
}
```

**OrderObserver**

```
class OrderObserver
{
    public function created(Order $order)
    {
        foreach (array_keys(OrderStatusEnum::STATUS) as $status) {
            Order::create([
                'order_id' => $order->id,
                'status' => $status,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
'attribute' => function (\App\Models\Order $item) { 
    return \App\Enums\OrderStatusEnum::find($item->status)->getName(); 
},
```

But I have mistake `Undefined array key 8`. Why?

Comment: Your `STATUS` array doesn't contain a value for `ui` (8).

Answer (score 0):

`array_keys` function will return your `ENUM` numbers set in `OrderStatusEnum` class.
if you look at this class, you can see that `"self::ui"` is not set in your `STATUS` array.
so you may change your array to:

```
const STATUS = [
    self::CREATED => 'enum.week.monday',
    self::PAID => 'enum.week.tuesday',
    self::we => 'enum.week.monday',
    self::re => 'enum.week.tuesday',
    self::tr => 'enum.week.monday',
    self::ty => 'enum.week.tuesday',
    self::yu => 'enum.week.monday',
    self::ui => 'enum.week.tuesday',
    self::io => 'enum.week.tuesday',
    self::uy => 'enum.week.monday',
];
```

Comment: Thanks. All I needed is to do migration